# Why does this not print anything back?

Tags: python, string

Making a function to return the number of characters in a word. This doesn't print anything?

```
def get_length(word):
  counter = 0
  for letter in word:
    counter += 1
  return counter
  print(counter)
```

Comment: The function exits immediatly on `return`. So anything afterwards, like the `print()`, is never executed.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to print after returning from the function which is not possible.

You must either print the value before `return`:

```
def get_length(word):
  counter = 0
  for letter in word:
    counter += 1
  print(counter)
  return counter
```

Or you can print the result from the function:

```
def get_length(word):
  counter = 0
  for letter in word:
    counter += 1
  return counter

print(get_length("example"))
```

Answer (score 0):

you are returning from the function before the print statement is reached, to fix it change it to:

```
def get_length(word):
  counter = 0
  for letter in word:
    counter += 1
  print(counter)
```

make sure to call the function as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
def get_length(word):
  counter = 0
  for letter in word:
    counter += 1
  print(counter)
  return counter
```

As the function is returning before printing that's why it was not printing

Answer (score 0):

Hey it would be nice if you could check if your input has text with semicolons and could you please state the python version ? i just tried your code and it worked as expected.

And as everyone else is saying you should write the print before the return statement as it means that you are leaving your fuction, making it impossible to get there.

Although somehow it is working for me.